# How to find $\overline{abc}_{7}-\overline{cba}_{7}=\overline{xy4}_{7}$?

Tags: number-systems, cryptarithm

The problem is as follows:

> Let:
>
> $\overline{abc}_{7}-\overline{cba}_{7}=\overline{xy4}_{7}$
>
> Assuming $a=b-c$
>
> Find: $cba_{7}$ in terms of decimal system.

How exactly should I do this?. Can someone help me here?.

The thing is I don't know how to deal with carry numerals.

So far the only thing which I spotted is that $c-a=4$

For this the only way to get this is assuming $c=6$ and $a=2$ thus it will not carry. Isn't it?.

But this is somewhat contradictory by looking on the third digit because it states $a-c=2-6=-4$

Which it cannot happen. Thus what am I doing wrong?. Can someone help me here?. My only requirement is a method which doesn't really uses much sophisticated math such as modular arithmetics or too many algebraic manipulations. Does it exist a way to do this more intuitively?

Comment: You have to use equations such as $\overline{abc}_{7}=a\cdot 7^2+b\cdot 7+c.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIG HINT

It is important to see that $c-a$ is not $4$. From the leading digit one has that $a$ is at least as big as $c$. So the only possibility is that $7+c-a=4$ i.e. there has been a carry. We therefore obtain $a=c+3$.

You should now be able to see that $\overline{abc}$ must be treated as $$\overline{(a-1)(b+6)(c+7)}$$.

The rest should be easy but I will add that there seems to be a convention that no leading digits are zero.

Comment: Why $7+c-a=4$? Is this an identity when you carry in a different from base 10 numbers?. What made you conclude that $\overline{abc}$ is $\overline{(a-1)(b+6)(c+7)}$  where do these 1,6 and 7 appears?. I assume 7 in the first digit is due is carrying?. Is this correct?. But why in the tenths digit it is six? and in the hundreds is minus 1?. Can you explain these?. If I follow your hint I'm getting $x=2$ and $y=6$. But how to get the $a$ and $b$?. Can you please attend these doubts?.

Comment: Yes:- x=2,y=6 is correct.

Comment: The 6 and 7 are the results of carries. It is necessary to carry 1 from the "a" column into the "b" column. Therefore a becomes a-1 and b becomes b+7. Then we need to carry 1 from the "b" column into the "c" column. Therefore b+7 becomes b+6 and c becomes c+7.

Comment: Why $a$ needs to carry to $b$?. This part is what I'm stuck. Assuming that part is taken for granted. The only possibility is that $c=1$ as $c$ cannot be zero and $a=4$. Now $b$ can take any value between $0 to 6$ **however** there is the equation in the problem which constrains those choices to only one as $a=b-c$ which limits the choices to $b=5$. Hence that mysterious number is $\overline{cba}_{7}=154_{7}$ which is $88_{10}$ and this checks with the official answer.

Comment: But would you mind to explain in your answer the reason **why** $a$ **must carry to $b$**. Please, do that so I can accept your answer.

Comment: Certainly. Note that originally  the middle column had "b take away b". Therefore there was no spare number to carry over unless it received a carry from a.

Comment: Thanks for that. It make all sense about it. I was thinking the same.

Answer (score 0):

$$a,b,c,x,y \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

$$abc-cba7 = xy4$$

$$abc = cba + xy4$$

So we want to end up with this addition result (in base 7).

\begin{array}{c}
     & c & b & a \\
   + & x & y & 4 \\
\hline
     & a & b & c
\end{array}

Let's start with the right column

\begin{array}{c}
     & c & b & \color{red}a \\
   + & x & y & \color{red}4 \\
\hline
     & a & b & \color{red}c
\end{array}

Either {$a+4=c$} or {$a+4 = 7+c$, which implies  $c=a-3$}.

From the last column, we conclude that $c < a$.  So $c = a-3$ and, because $a+4 = 7+c$,
we must carry a $1$.

\begin{array}{c}
     & c & \color{red}{\overset{\displaystyle 1}{b}} & a \\
   + & x & \color{red}y & 4 \\
\hline
     & a & \color{red}b & c
\end{array}

So, either $(b+1)+y = b$ (which implies $y=-1$)
or $(b+1)+y = 7+b$ (which implies $y=6$.

We conclude that $y=6$ and we must carry a $1$.

\begin{array}{c}
     & \color{red}{\overset{\displaystyle 1}{c}} 
     & \overset{\displaystyle 1}{b} & a \\
   + & \color{red}x & 6 & 4 \\
\hline
     & \color{red}a & b & c
\end{array}

So it must be true that $(c+1)+x = a$. Substituting $c=a-3$, we conclude $x=2$.

\begin{array}{c}
     & \overset{\displaystyle 1}{c} & \overset{\displaystyle 1}{b} & a \\
   + & 3 & 6 & 4 \\
\hline
     & a & b & c
\end{array}

So, if you want unique answers

$a=3 \qquad b =5 \qquad c=0 \qquad x = 2 \qquad y=6$

\begin{array}{c}
     & 0 & 5 & 3 \\
   + & 2 & 6 & 4 \\
\hline
     & 3 & 5 & 0
\end{array}

$$cba_7 = 053_7 = 38$$

$$xy4_7 = 264_7 = 144$$

$$abc_7 = 350_7 = 182$$

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful step by step approach but please check the equations because $y=6$ and $x=2$. By principle $b$ can take any value from $0$ to $6$. But there is a constrain in the problem which indicates $a=b-c$ this limits the choices. The official answer is $88_{10}$. I don't know why your method isn't working?. It seems logical.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell - Thanks. I'm getting old and sometimes have trouble keeping all my ducks in order.